# update-grub: Generating grub configuration file ... error: failed to get canonical path...No path or device is specified

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

I'm on Ubuntu 22.04 on a dual boot system with Windows 11. Everything works smoothly, but when I'm trying to [install the Heroku CLI using the recommended script](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli#install-with-ubuntu-debian-apt-get), I'm seeing the following error:-

```
curl https://cli-assets.heroku.com/install-ubuntu.sh | sh
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  1232  100  1232    0     0   8898      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  8927
This script requires superuser access to install apt packages.
You will be prompted for your password by sudo.
[sudo] password for user: 
+ dpkg -s apt-transport-https
+ echo deb https://cli-assets.heroku.com/apt ./
+ dpkg -s heroku-toolbelt
+ true
+ curl https://cli-assets.heroku.com/apt/release.key
+ apt-key add -
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0Warning: apt-key is deprecated. Manage keyring files in trusted.gpg.d instead (see apt-key(8)).
100  1753  100  1753    0     0  19408      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 19477
OK
+ apt-get update
Hit:1 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Hit:2 https://cli-assets.heroku.com/apt ./ InRelease                                                                                                   
Hit:3 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease                                                                                              
Hit:4 https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                                                                          
Hit:5 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease                                               
Hit:6 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease                                             
Hit:7 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease                          
Hit:8 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/danielrichter2007/grub-customizer/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Hit:9 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/git-core/ppa/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Hit:10 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/rodsmith/refind/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Hit:11 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/yannubuntu/boot-repair/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
W: https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/dists/jammy/InRelease: Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), see the DEPRECATION section in apt-key(8) for details.
W: https://cli-assets.heroku.com/apt/./InRelease: Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), see the DEPRECATION section in apt-key(8) for details.
+ apt-get install -y heroku
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-modules-5.15.0-25-generic : Depends: linux-image-5.15.0-25-generic but it is not going to be installed or
                                            linux-image-unsigned-5.15.0-25-generic but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).


~/code [ master ] $ 


sudo apt --fix-broken install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra cmake-data dh-elpa-helper gcc gcc-11 gstreamer1.0-vaapi icu-devtools libasan6 libatomic1 libatomic1:i386 libbrotli-dev
  libbsd0:i386 libc-dev-bin libc-devtools libcc1-0 libcrypt-dev libdatrie-dev libdbus-1-dev libdeflate-dev libdpkg-perl libdrm-amdgpu1:i386
  libdrm-nouveau2:i386 libdrm-radeon1:i386 libdrm2:i386 libedit2:i386 libegl-dev libegl1-mesa-dev libelf1:i386 libepoxy-dev libexpat1:i386 libffi-dev
  libffi8:i386 libfile-fcntllock-perl libfribidi-dev libgcc-11-dev libgl-dev libglapi-mesa:i386 libgles-dev libgles1 libglib2.0-dev-bin
  libglvnd-core-dev libglvnd-dev libglvnd0:i386 libglx-dev libgraphite2-dev libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-0 libharfbuzz-gobject0 libice-dev
  libicu70:i386 libitm1 libjbig-dev libjsoncpp25 libllvm13:i386 liblsan0 liblzma-dev libmd0:i386 libnsl-dev libnvidia-cfg1-510 libnvidia-common-510
  libnvidia-compute-510:i386 libnvidia-decode-510 libnvidia-decode-510:i386 libnvidia-egl-wayland1 libnvidia-encode-510 libnvidia-encode-510:i386
  libnvidia-extra-510 libnvidia-fbc1-510 libnvidia-gl-510 libnvidia-gl-510:i386 libopengl-dev libpcre16-3 libpcre2-16-0 libpcre2-posix3 libpcre32-3
  libpcrecpp0v5 libpixman-1-dev libpng-tools libpthread-stubs0-dev librhash0 libsensors5:i386 libsepol-dev libsigc++-2.0-dev libsm-dev libstdc++6:i386
  libthai-dev libtiffxx5 libtirpc-dev libtsan0 libubsan1 libva-wayland2 libvulkan1:i386 libwayland-bin libwayland-client0:i386 libwayland-dev
  libx11-6:i386 libx11-dev libx11-xcb1:i386 libxau-dev libxau6:i386 libxcb-dri2-0:i386 libxcb-dri3-0:i386 libxcb-glx0:i386 libxcb-present0:i386
  libxcb-randr0:i386 libxcb-render0-dev libxcb-shm0:i386 libxcb-shm0-dev libxcb-sync1:i386 libxcb-xfixes0:i386 libxcb1:i386 libxcb1-dev
  libxcomposite-dev libxcursor-dev libxdamage-dev libxdmcp-dev libxdmcp6:i386 libxext-dev libxext6:i386 libxfixes-dev libxfixes3:i386 libxi-dev
  libxinerama-dev libxkbcommon-dev libxml2:i386 libxnvctrl0 libxrandr-dev libxrender-dev libxshmfence1:i386 libxtst-dev libxxf86vm1:i386 manpages-dev
  mesa-vulkan-drivers:i386 nvidia-compute-utils-510 nvidia-settings nvidia-utils-510 pango1.0-tools pkg-config rpcsvc-proto screen-resolution-extra
  wayland-protocols x11proto-dev xorg-sgml-doctools xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-510 xtrans-dev
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  linux-image-unsigned-5.15.0-25-generic
Suggested packages:
  fdutils linux-doc | linux-source-5.15.0 linux-tools linux-headers-5.15.0-25-generic linux-modules-extra-5.15.0-25-generic
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  linux-image-5.15.0-25-generic
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  linux-image-unsigned-5.15.0-25-generic
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 1 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/11.2 MB of archives.
After this operation, 268 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
dpkg: linux-image-5.15.0-25-generic: dependency problems, but removing anyway as you requested:
 linux-modules-5.15.0-25-generic depends on linux-image-5.15.0-25-generic | linux-image-unsigned-5.15.0-25-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-5.15.0-25-generic is to be removed.
  Package linux-image-unsigned-5.15.0-25-generic is not installed.

(Reading database ... 208769 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing linux-image-5.15.0-25-generic (5.15.0-25.25) ...
/etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Deleting /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-25-generic
/etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub:
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'
Generating grub configuration file ...
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: error: failed to get canonical path of `/boot/grub/unicode.pf2GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=false'.
No path or device is specified.
Usage: grub-probe [OPTION...] [OPTION]... [PATH|DEVICE]
Try 'grub-probe --help' or 'grub-probe --usage' for more information.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 64
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-5.15.0-25-generic (--remove):
 installed linux-image-5.15.0-25-generic package post-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: too many errors, stopping
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-5.15.0-25-generic
Processing was halted because there were too many errors.
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I suppose the key error here is this:-

```
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'
Generating grub configuration file ...
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: error: failed to get canonical path of `/boot/grub/unicode.pf2GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=false'.
No path or device is specified.
```

I can see that there's some issue when it's trying to create the grub configuration file.

I'm just not sure how to resolve this or even what the issue really is about.

My dual boot works just fine. My grub2 menu loads at bootup and I'm able to go to windows and Ubuntu from there. Everything is as it should be. But I'm seeing this.

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably, there is a missing new line in your `/etc/default/grub` file.

My guess is that the command `update-grub` is trying to parse the `/etc/default/grub` file and finds an inconsistent fint path, becuase two separate lines are merged.

Check if there is a line containing `/boot/grub/unicode.pf2GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=false` and put an <kbd>ENTER</kbd> just between `.pf2` and `GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER`

Comment: You did it! Thank you so much!!! I was worried I was going to have to reinstall ubuntu. Thank goodness I posted here. You saved so much of my time!

Comment: There is a slight error in this answer. At least in my Ubuntu-Unity 22.04.1 LTS: The line actually has quotes around "unicode.pf2", so the line-break needs to be after the closing quote. Either way, this is a result of a generated file bug.